# Best relational model when you want STI but you know you shouldn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

I'm looking to understand what would be the best Relational Model for a Rails app.

It sounds like Single Table Inheritance would "work" to a degree, but not really when I consider how varied the Child Models would be in terms of their "Schema" and fields.

The situation, would be something where I have lots of different types of `Appraisal`, and I want the flexibility to do stuff like `Appraisals.first.type = CarAppraisal` or `Appraisals.count = 142`, where that `count` would be the sum of multiple different sub-model classes of `Appraisal` (eg HouseAppraisal, CatAppraisal).

Master Model Type: `Appraisal`

```
class Appraisal < Application Record
  has_one :car_appraisals
  has_one :house_appraisals
  has_one :life_appraisals
  #insert other has_one _appraisals I might add in the future
end
```

---

Child Model Type: `House Appraisal`

```
class HouseAppraisal < Application Record
  belongs_to :appraisal
end
```

---

Child Model Type: `Car Appraisal`

```
class CarAppraisal < Application Record
  belongs_to :appraisal
end
```

---

**etc etc etc**

**What I've Considered**

- I thought of something where I could utilise a `has_many, through: xxx` but I can't really put my finger on how this might work?
- I know I put `has_one` in the Parent Appraisal model, and that isn't quite correct given it implies it would contain one of each, when it fact it would be only one of them.
- To complicate things, I'm actually mapping the `Appraisal` model across ActiveRecord (Postgres) and the Child models (eg `PetAppraisal`) mapped across MongoId (MongoDB), given they vary a fair bit in schema, but I don't think that should really change much in terms of the overall ERD.

Comment: What fields are common to all appraisal types? Can you pull those common fields out as an "Appraisal" model and all the other fields are different kinds of models that `belong_to :appraisal` ?

Comment: Thanks Taryn, that's along the lines of what I was thinking could be possible. I guess I would then have the common fields, **plus** another field for `foreign_key` eg: `child_id`, which would reference the child model. How would this go though in terms of ActiveRecord support for associations, saving of records etc, when there is no `has_many` or `has_one` association the other way on the Parent Model?

Comment: I was suggesting not bothering with STI parent/child modelling at all... a CarAppraisal could be a separate table from a LifeAppraisal... with its own columns... but the common fields are all in the Appraisal table. You then use a polymorphic association from the Appraisal model to refer back to the other things... eg appraisal `has_one :appraisable, :polymorphic => true` So you can use the Appraisal table to find all the appraisable-things...

Comment: @nickj It seems to me you might be building something like tree structure. [Here is some blog post on that](https://www.leighhalliday.com/tree-structures-in-your-rails-models)